# Error in MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead.

connect.php

error in:

```
<?php function connections(){
$user="root";
$pass="";
$server="localhost";
$db="db";
$con=mysql_connect($server,$user,$pass) or die ('Connection failed: '.mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die ('Could db: '.mysql_error());
return $con;
}
?>
```

insertcase.php

error in:

```
$con=connections();

$query="insert into caso values ('','$date','name')";

$cierto=mysql_query($query,$con);

if(!$cierto){
echo "No saved";
}
else {
$query= mysql_query("SELECT @@identity  AS id ");
 if ($row = mysql_fetch_row($query)) 
 {
   $id = trim($row[0]);
}
echo '<script>alert (" tickect is:  '.$id.'");   window.location="../index.php";</script>';
}
```

please help... :)

Comment: The question is how to resolve the notice? It tells you `use mysqli or PDO instead`.

Comment: it means whatever book/tutorial you are following is outdated. get a modern book/tutorial that teaches you the new methods.

Comment: What is the new syntax?

Comment: It depends, choose a driver and view the manual. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php or http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: let me google that for you: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: The problem is that when modifying connections.php, insert case.php throws a problem

Comment: you need to do changes in each files

Comment: that problem/error being what? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php add that to your query and use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: and where is this defined? `$date`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PDO to connect to a mysql server.

here is an example.

```
 <?php
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "username";
  $password = "password";

 try {
     $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
     // set the PDO error mode to exception
     $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     echo "Connected successfully";
     }
 catch(PDOException $e)
     {
     echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
     }
 ?>
```

Comment: the problem now is in:  $cierto=mysql_query($query,$con);

Comment: @SpartanDev please read your error messages. `The mysql extension is deprecated` meaning every `mysql_` is deprecated.